# Node.js: long delay

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout

There is an event after which comes feedback on my server. I have to send a message to exactly one hour after the event.

I can use a `setTimeout()` but it seems it will not be good.

Perhaps it would be better if I start `cron` which will check the status of an event from database(such as every minute)

Does anyone know of a greater good option for the implementation of such a long delay?

Comment: Personally, I would use `cron` for this purpose. Have it tick every x minutes and keep the timestamps for actions in your DB.

Comment: I see no problems with setTimeout(). Please, explain why it would not be good?

Comment: @teroi in case if the server is restarted then the command will not be executed

Comment: Good point @Maria. One alternative would be to use something like node-schedule and save/load the rules to/from some local storage on change and server start up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you require 100% reliability use a cron job.  The problem with a cron job is that your code will be spread around the place and it would require configuration each time you set up a new server.  An alternate approach would be to use an npm package like [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron).

The issue with `setTimeout()` is that if your application crashes/restarts the future function call will be lost.  However, each time your application starts, it could query the DB and see all missing timeouts and set them appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am inclined to the cron and you dispelled my doubts